# how to restrict unwanted image storage in wordpress media upload

Tags: php, wordpress, media, wordpress-theming, thumbnails

iam using wordpress and when i upload a new image it tend to crop in different size (thumbnail(150*150), medium(300*200), large ) and stores it. For a single image it generates around 4 different images which are generally not used. I need to restrict it to just thumbnail and original image. how to do it.

Comment: You can also try asking on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OMG i really screwed up, it was dam easy in wordpress. you just need to mention the value of medium and large images as 0 in media settings and that would do...

Comment: add that as the answer and accept it. Might be useful for a future user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to mention the value of medium and large images as 0 in media settings in wordpress.